# Convert Json Date To JavaScript Date But Without Convert Local Machine TimeZone

Tags: javascript, json

I'm got Utc date time from my server and converted into timezone in service itself. Now i got timezone converted Json format date time output. But not human readable format.

i have try this

```
new Date(parseInt(jsonDate.slice(6, -1), 10))
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: example of your jsonDate - I didn't think json **had** a formalised date format